# Split View Application, how to call a function that is situated in root view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm making an split-view application. In RootController there is a function to to the next cell of the tableview:

```
-(void)goToNextCell
{
    NSIndexPath *nextCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentSelection.row+1 inSection:currentSelection.section];

    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:nextCell animated:YES scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    NSLog(@"Went to next Cell!");
}
```

And in the detailed view a have button NEXT to go to the next cell:

```
-(IBAction)goToNextTextClicked:(id)sender
{
    //Should call this function ^^^^ HOW?(((    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have typically done this kind of thing by defining a delegate protocol within my detail view controller class header like this:

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate
- (void)didClickGoToNext;
@end

@interface DetailViewController {
    id<DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In my implementation of the detailed view controller I would then have:

```
-(IBAction)goToNextTextClicked:(id)sender {
    [delegate didClickGoToNext];
}
```

Finally, I would have by root view controller implement the DetailViewControllerDelegate protocol and set itself as the delegate. The root view controller now will be notified when the detail view controller's button has been pressed, and it can react accordingly.